# ASP.NET 5 DI app setting outside controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net5

I can DI app setting in the controller like this

```
 private IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings;
 public CompanyInfoController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
 {
     this.appSettings = appSettings;
 }
```

But how to DI that in my custom class like this

```
  private IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings;
  public PermissionFactory(IOptions<AppSettings> appSetting)
  {
      this.appSettings = appSettings;
  }
```

my register in Startup.cs is

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The "proper" way

Register your custom class in the DI, the same way you register other dependencies in `ConfigureServices` method, for example:

```
services.AddTransient<PermissionFactory>();
```

(Instead of `AddTransient`, you can use `AddScoped`, or any other lifetime that you need)

Then add this dependency to the constructor of your controller:

```
public CompanyInfoController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings, PermissionFactory permFact)
```

Now, DI knows about `PermissionFactory`, can instantiate it and will inject it into your controller.

If you want to use `PermissionFactory` in `Configure` method, just add it to it's parameter list:

```
Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, PermissionFactory prov)
```

Aspnet will do it's magic and inject the class there.

#### The "nasty" way

If you want to instantiate `PermissionFactory` somewhere deep in your code, you can also do it in a little nasty way - store reference to `IServiceProvider` in `Startup` class:

```
internal static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get;set; }

Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider prov) {
   ServiceProvider = prov;
   ...
}
```

Now you can access it like this:

```
var factory = Startup.ServiceProvider.GetService<PermissionFactory>();
```

Again, DI will take care of injecting `IOptions<AppSettings>` into `PermissionFactory`.

[Asp.Net 5 Docs in Dependency Injection](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html)

Comment: I want to inject AppSetting into PermissionFactory not add PermissionFactory  into CompanyInfoController

Comment: The question is: where do you want to access this `PermissionFactory` class. If some class `B` uses it, you should add `PermissionFactory` to `B`'s contructor, and so on, until you reach some "entry point", which probably is a Controller.

Comment: but... entry is not controller..so I say "outside controller"

Comment: What matters is that the class "outside the controller" is also resolved by the DI container. So if you have a controller and the controller depends on A, and A depends on B and C, and C depends on D, E, and F, etc., the container will inject the needed dependencies into all of them when it resolves the controller. That's the most likely entry point, but it could also be a filter.

Comment: It's a action filter

Comment: About `var factory = Startup.ServiceProvider.prov.GetService<PermissionFactory>();` Do you check that? not work for me event remove .prov and modify GetService

Comment: I mark this answer but you need to check the code in "The "nasty" way" and if some one need information of DI in action filter can ref to [Dependency Injection in Attributes: don’t do it!](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98)

Comment: code in nasty way not working. "The non-generic method 'IServiceProvider.GetService(Type)' cannot be used with type arguments"

Answer (score 3):

I recommend not passing `AppSettings`. A class shouldn't depend on something vague - it should depend on exactly what it needs, or close to it. ASP.NET Core makes it easier to move away from the old pattern of depending on `AppSettings`. If your class depends on `AppSettings` then you can't really see from the constructor what it depends on. It could depend on any key. If it depends on a more specific interface then its dependency is clearer, more explicit, and you can mock that interface when unit testing.

You can create an interface with the specific settings that your class needs (or something less specific but not too broad) and a class that implements it - for example,

```
    public interface IFooSettings
    {
        string Name { get; }
        IEnumerable Foos { get; }
    }

    public interface IFoo
    {
        string Color { get;  }
        double BarUnits { get;  }
    }

    public class FooSettings : IFooSettings
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Foo> FooList { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable Foos
        {
            get
            {
                if (FooList == null) FooList = new List<Foo>();
                return FooList.Cast<IFoo>();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Foo : IFoo
    {
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public double BarUnits { get; set; }
    }
```

Then add a .json file, fooSettings.json:

```
    {
      "FooSettings": {
        "Name": "MyFooSettings",
        "FooList": [
          {
            "Color": "Red",
            "BarUnits": "1.5"
          },      {
            "Color": "Blue",
            "BarUnits": "3.14159'"
          },      {
            "Color": "Green",
            "BarUnits": "-0.99999"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Then, in `Startup()` (in Startup.cs) where we specify what goes into our `Configuration`, add fooSettings.json:

```
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddJsonFile("fooSettings.json");
```

Finally, in `ConfigureServices()` (also in Startup.cs) tell it to load an instance of `FooSettings`, cast it as `IFooSetting`s (so the properties appear read-only) and supply that single instance for all dependencies on `IFooSettings`:

```
    var fooSettings = (IFooSettings)ConfigurationBinder.Bind<FooSettings>(
        Configuration.GetConfigurationSection("FooSettings"));
    services.AddInstance(typeof (IFooSettings), fooSettings);
```

Now your class - controller, filter, or anything else created by the DI container - can have a dependency on `IFooSettings` and it will be supplied from the .json file. But you can mock `IFooSettings` for unit testing.

[Original blog post](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/03/19/aspdotnet5-core-configuration-settings-starting-from-zero.html) - it's mine so I'm not plagiarizing.

Comment: How do I access the Name from Foo Interface in a static method?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the question.

Comment: Basically, I can access the Interface values in controllers but how do I access in class library project?

Comment: I think that may require a different question. I'm not following what you want to access and where. It sounds like something different so I shouldn't answer it in this question, and the comments aren't an ideal place to answer it either.

Comment: Thank you, I will continue my searching to access DI in non-controller class

Answer (score 2):

You can do dependency injection in your non-controller classes as well.

In your `startup` class,

```
public class Startup
{
  public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

  public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
  {
        // Set up configuration sources.
     var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
             .AddEnvironmentVariables();
     Configuration = builder.Build();
  }
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
     // register other dependencies also here
     services.AddInstance<IConfiguration>(Configuration);     
  }
}
```

Now in your custom class, Have the constructor accept an implementation of `IConfiguration`

```
private IConfiguration configuration;
public PermissionFactory(IConfiguration configuration)
{
  this.configuration = configuration;
}
public void SomeMethod()
{
  var someSection = this.configuration.GetSection("SomeSection");
  var someValue= this.configuration.Get<string>("YourItem:SubItem");
}
```

Comment: so...if I change the section name in project.json then I need to check the hole project who use this section?

Comment: So if I want to instantiate PermissionFactory somewhere other than a controller I can just call `var pf = new PermissionFactory()` and it'll work automatically? What happens if I want to pass manual parameters into that constructor as well?

Comment: Don't `new` the instance at all! Use DI everywhere in your code.

Comment: What you mean don't `new` the instance? the class can't be used without initialize the instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to DI to action filter reference to [Action filters, service filters and type filters in ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/06/action-filters-service-filters-type-filters-asp-net-5-mvc-6/) service filter part.