# access appsetting from data layer without creating instantiation with parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

How can i access my "appsettings.js" values in Business/Data layer without creating instantiation in the constructor level.

I can access all values in the controller but i don't want to send to all my layers like passing constructor parameter.

I am trying to understand this post but i don't understand fully. can some one provide me some sample code with out creating instantiation

[ASP.NET 5 DI app setting outside controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904174/asp-net-5-di-app-setting-outside-controller)

**Controller - Services - DBServices (without parameter constructor?)**

**appsetting.json**

```
"DbSettings":{
    "ConnectionString" : "TESTING Connection string here"
  }
```

**Controller**:

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        public TestController(IOptions<DbSettings> dbSettings)
        {
            _balService = new BALServices(dbSettings.Value); // passing parameter "dbsetting" to constructor which i don't want.
        }
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.Configure<DbSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("DbSettings"));
            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
```

**Dbsettings.cs**

```
public class DbSettings
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework isn’t really designed to allow you to do that. ASP.NET Core uses dependency injection and kind of *forces* you to follow it, since pretty much everything is inaccessible outside of the DI container. So whenever something *depends* on something, then it should make that dependency clear by expecting it in the constructor. That is the way it is designed.

That being said, you creating a new instance of `BALServices` isn’t really in the spirit of dependency injection either. If you want to use `BALServices` in the controller, then instead of creating an instance of it itself, the controller should just *depend* on that type.

So you would change the controller to look like this:

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly BALServices _balService;
    public TestController(BALServices balService)
    {
        _balService = balService;
    }
}
```

Now, the controller does not need to worry about *how* it could possibly create that object. It just depends on it being there and letting someone else figure that out. And that’s exactly what dependency injection is about.

In order to make that work, of course you now need to adjust your `BALServices` to depend on those `IOptions<DbSettings>` instead:

```
public class BALServices
{
    private readonly DbSettings _dbSettings;
    public BALServices(IOptions<DbSettings> dbSettings)
    {
        _dbSettings = dbSettings.Value;
    }
}
```

And then you only need to register this service in your `Startup`:

```
services.AddScoped<BALServices>();
```

And now you have `TestController` depend on the actual service it wants to use, and `BALServices` depend on the configuration it requires. And the DI container will automatically provide you with what you need.